# Reposition a logo on blogger.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Hi guys, I can't seem to move the logo "written words" to the right, I've been trying for literally 5 hours, is there any way I can do so?

Also, can I make this space a little bit smaller: https://pasteboard.co/HjMLi8u.png

[Here's the blog link](https://newtest123d4.blogspot.com)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  You will receive better responses by posting some code that shows what you have tried so far and what isn't working.

Comment: I have tried a lot of codes, but none of them worked

Comment: What shall I do Kyle Please? I added a link to my blog

Comment: There we go https://newtest123d4.blogspot.com

Comment: please like add the code _your_  working with.

Answer (score 0):

say you name the class for the logo .logo

```
.logo {
    float: right;
```

}
would work but I am thinking you want a better looking result.
say the nav bar up at the top is .navbar

```
.navbar {
    //your code so far
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}
```

I suggest not using floating elements, mostly because if you want your site to look good on a mobile device they will still float their and possibly cover eachother or other elements. I would be able to help more, had you provided code

Edit: I looked at your page and I see that you seem to be using a css template, which will make this so much harder for you, I suggest coding your own stylesheet, as you don't know how compatible the elements are with each other, and it makes it harder to personalize

Comment: Gotcha, btw none of the mentioned code is in the code, here's the entire good: https://file.io/CbKlzX